# Script has to be executed X times in 24h. How do I randomize that?

Tags: php, bash, cron

I have a PHP script, which does something in a matter of seconds (not running for a long time). I need this script to be executed, **let's assume**, 12  (this can change) times a day. 24 / 12 = 2 hours.

I could just execute the script each 2 hours, but I need it to be randomized along the 24 hours.

That means that script doesn't have to be executed at 01:**05** PM, 03:**05** PM, 05:**05** PM, but rather at 01:**37** PM, 03:**11** PM, 05:**46** PM. I guess you've understand the point. Sorry for not being very clear.

*(cron & other tools (if required) can be installed. running debian 6)*

**Bounty (100 rep) will be offered for a working solution.**

Comment: Do you care about how long between intervals? and the minimum number is 12 or the exact number of times to be run a day is 12?

Comment: @hackartist the number can be anything. usually will be 30-50. I don't care about how long if there is a minimum interval of time between executions.

Comment: You could run cron every 15 min, and decide with php script to run exact job or not, have some array with times when it should run if time fits then run if not exit job.

Comment: Must it run **exactly** XXX times a day, or *about* XXX times a day ?

Comment: @wildplasser 1-2 misses are acceptable.

Comment: For wakkerbot, I had a program whose sole purpose was to exit zero or one randomly, with  a probability xxx/yyy. If it returned zero ("go") it also did a random sleep (1...60) to avoid the second-counter to be zero all the time. As an extra, the time of last excution was stored, and it would not proceed if fewer than zzz minutes ago. All this was intended to avoid detection and flooding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want your script to run `N` times a day. Then create a bash script  `my_php_runner.bash` like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=12  # 50 times a day

let WAIT_TIME=86400/$N

while [[ $n -gt 0 ]]; do
    php yourscript.php

    # Sleep for $WAIT +/- 300 seconds
    sleep $(( $WAIT - 300 + $RANDOM%600 ))
    ((n--))
done
```

It will run your script 12 times, waiting between 115 and 125 minutes between runs. Then add something like

```
0 0 * * * my_php_runner.bash
```

in `cron` to run the bash script once a day.

Comment: actually, this is a very good idea. but in case N=50, sleeping for +- 300 seconds would be too much, and thus the script won't get executed for 50 times.

Comment: True. I hardcoded the 300 for simplicity, but you could make it something like WAIT_TIME/10.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:  Setup a cron to tell it to run every 2 hours like this

```
0 /2 * * * php youscript.php
```

This says run yourscript.php every other hour on the hour. Then in the top of the php code itself just put:

```
sleep(rand(5*60,50*60));
```

this will make the script pause a random amount of time between 5 and 50 minutes before doing its work. You can change the min and max of the random number to ensure that there is a minimum time between runs.

If you wanted it to run 24 times instead do

```
0 * * * * php youscript.php
```

or even 48 times a day

```
0,30 * * * * php youscript.php
```

Comment: yes but what if I had to execute it not 12 times a day, but 50? I just said 12 so it is be easier to understand my needs :)

Comment: This shows how, it is easiest with numbers that are a multiple of 12 but you can see [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) how the cron syntax works (most likely the cron is already installed on your computer and you just have to edit the instruction file)

Answer (score 0):

You can always `sleep(rand(60, 1.5 * 60))` at the start of the cronjob to offset its execution. You will have an idle PHP process during this time, which might or might not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, your cronjob will run at fixed times, after which it can sleep for a random period before starting its work.

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly must run X times per day:

- Manually (or make a simple script) to divide the day in to X portions.
- Make a cron line for each portion.
- Delay your script a random amount between 0 and 24H/x during run.

If not:

- Cron run at midnight.
- PHP delays using poisson distribution then processes.
- End of script runs a new script unless its processing crossed midnight.